# How to convert javascript object into json without using "JSON.stringify" method?

Tags: javascript, json, stringify

Is there any way to convert javascript object into JSON.

I can not use

`JSON.stringify(<obj>)`

Because there is no stringify method in the JSON object in the following link.

[Link](http://www.4luggage.com)

Example:

```
var obj = {'x':1,'y':2}
```

Now if I'll run

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

Then I'm getting this error.

> error: TypeError: Object # has no method 'stringify'

Comment: No repo, http://jsfiddle.net/nXQxC/

Comment: Fiddle works fine in Chrome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the website overrides the actual JSON object with their own.

```
> JSON
> Object {toStr: function, quote: function}
```

Try using `JSON.toStr(object)`

Comment: Thanks Man. You are observant!

Answer (score 2):

It appears that some code/library has overridden the global JSON object. `JSON.toStr` is fine but if you want the original `JSON` objet back you can always create an invisible frame and use its global objects

```
OriginalJSON = (function() {
  var e = document.createElement('frame');
  e.style.display = 'none';
  var f = document.body.appendChild(e);
  return f.contentWindow.JSON;
})()

OriginalJSON.stringify({a: 1})
```

This is a technique that works for all global objects that has been overridden for some reason. As an alternative you can always copy only the `stringify` method

```
JSON.stringify = (function() {
  var e = document.createElement('frame');
  e.style.display = 'none';
  var f = document.body.appendChild(e);
  return f.contentWindow.JSON.stringify;
})()

// Now JSON.stringify is back
JSON.stringify({a: 1})
```

Comment: I really appreciate this explanative answer, because with this method it`s possible to solve another overrides. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`stringify` method depends on your browser.

So if you cannot find `JSON.stringify()`, maybe the browser you're using is not compatible to JSON API, you could include this library to make it there:

[json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js)

Comment: Browser supports because I can use it in other sites!

Comment: But I'm curious about your situation, could you provide any sample to see why only your site JSON got blocked?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using external library, for example [JSON 3](http://bestiejs.github.io/json3/) is a good choice.